# Get the value of an ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have a textarea and a checkbox, as soon as I check the checkbox, I want to get the value of my checkbox in the textarea.

```html
<div class="message-container">
  <textarea 
    *ngIf="mode === 1"
    id="message"
    rows=8
    (ngModelChange)="updateView($event)"
    [ngModel]="message"
    value="formattedMessage" 
    placeholder="{{'Test_NOTE' | translate}} +{{ExempleIWantToGet}}">
  </textarea>
        
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Exemple</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="ExempleIWantToGet"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

When I did this, I got True or False instead of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the code snippets. It will populate value when user checked the checkbox.
app.component.html

```
<input type="text" [value]="chk.checked?ExempleIWantToGet:''">
<input #chk type="checkbox" (ngModel)="checkBoxValue" />
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  ExempleIWantToGet = 'Angular 5';
  checkBoxValue: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

You can get the value of `checkbox` in `textarea` using `click` event.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="message-container">
   <textarea id="message" rows=8 [ngModel]="message" 
    value="{{ExempleIWantToGet}}">
   </textarea>

   <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="ExempleIWantToGet">
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  ExempleIWantToGet = 'Your Value';
  message: any;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be addaded to the initial message

Comment: Let me explain it to you, if i check the "checkbox" the value will be addaded in the end of the textarea if not i want to keep the initial message, so as soon as i write my message if i check the box it will add in the end the value if not i keep writing my initial message

Comment: value means your checkbox value right?  What is the value of your `checkbox`

Comment: Exemple i'm connected to the app when i check the box it will get me my username addaded, not true or false but "username" if checked